# ImageView seems larger

Tags: android, android-imageview

Here is my problem:
I put a image with resolution 200x200 in a imageview with height and width both be 200dip, but the image shown seemed larger than 200x200, here is how I found the problem.

I use below code to get the width and height of my screen. And found out my screen is 540x800, but the image width is larger than half of my screen.

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    width = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    height = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

Is there anyone who can tell me why. Below is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation = "vertical"
android:background = "@drawable/mainbg2"
 >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout_menu_normal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img_menu_normal"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_normal"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's the density (pixels per inch) of your screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview).

> Density-independent pixel (dp)
>   A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
>
> The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the
>   system for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system
>   transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based
>   on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units
>   to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a
>   240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use
>   dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display
>   of your UI on screens with different densities.

So I assume that your device is not mdpi which use bigger scale ratio. If you want to make exact pixel size on you device you can use `200px`. But first check the documentations link above.

Answer (score 0):

it's display 200X200 dp size image in view you can check using this xmp change in you file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_menu_normal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_menu_normal"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

i hope you can understant what happen there. i am set image in centre of relative view and change background color of imageview to black and main view bg color to white.it's working code.